# Using C# how to express VBA "select case control.ID"

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

In VBA, I use below code to control Ribbon xml,

```
Sub paragraphs_style(ByVal control As IRibbonControl)    
Select Case control.ID
        Case "article_type" 
           xxxxxx
End Select
end sub
```

but in c#, how to express this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch):

```
switch (control.ID)
{
   case "article_type":
       // executable code
       break;
   case "something else":
       //
       break;
   case "A":
   case "B":
       // here, flow falls through, equivalent to Case "A","B" in VBA
       break;
   default:
       // equivalent to Case Else in VBA.
       break;
}
```